# How can you call a method after data is being fetched with useAxios hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I'm working on a project using React and react-hooks. I'm trying to invoke a method after a response is returned by the back-end. At the moment I'm using the Axios-hooks library to React to make the calls:

```
export const useDataFromServer = (dataObjectId) => {
    return useAxios(
        {
            url: `/data/${dataObjectId}`,
            method: 'GET',
        },
        {
            manual: manual,
        }
    );
}
```

I`m trying to implement my own hook to wrap the useAxios call, since I couldn't find any way to do it from the useAxios documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-hooks:

```
export function useAxiosWithResponseCallback(config, options, callback) {
    const [isCallbackCalled, setIsCallbackCalled] = useState(false);
    const [axiosState, execute] = useAxios(config, options);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (axiosState.loading) {
            setIsCallbackCalled(false);
        } else {
            if (!isCallbackCalled) {
                if (callback && typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback([axiosState, execute]);
                }
                setIsCallbackCalled(true);
            }
        }
    }, [
        axiosState,
        isCallbackCalled,
        callback,
    ]);

    return [
        axiosState,
        execute,
    ];
}
```

but I'm not sure whether it will work in all cases.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

useAxios is Promise based.

```
 const [{}, yourRequest] = useAxios(
    {
      ...AXIOS_CONFIG
    },
    { manual: true }
  )
```

And then you do

```
yourRequest(yourData).then(here is your callback)
```